# Как можно передать данные из одного дочернего компонента в другой?

Tags: javascript, html, angular2, typescript

Здравствуйте. Я только приступил к изучению Angular. Постал вопрос передачи данных с одного дочернего компонента в другой дочерний компонент (из метода одной компоненты срабатывает метод в другой). Знаю, что передаются данные с помощью Iput,Output, VievChild и тд. К сожалению, не знаю как лучше передавать данные в моем случае. Был бы признателен за практически примеры работы данных директив или ссылки на примеры. Заранее благодарю.

Comment: уже было много таких же вопросов. наверное вам это подойдет http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/12/01/angular-2-communicating-between-components-with-observable-subject

Comment: читай офф документацию, там все есть с подробными примерами

Answer (score 0):

Почитайте документацию [Component Interaction](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction).
Или пройдите полностью руководство [Tour of Heroes](https://angular.io/tutorial) от разработчиков и многие вещи вам статут понятны.